# Meaning of "Censi passivi"

Tags: word-meaning, meaning

I think 'censi passivi' must be some sort of tax, but can anybody elaborate?

The original sentence (in a list of sums of money spent) is:

> Item paga per censi passivi per denari pigliati ad interesse sin oggi per diversi bisogni

Comment: Can you provide us with some more context? What text is this excerpt taken from?

Comment: Seconded, some context would help. That sentence looks like it has been machine-translated to me. Grammatically it makes little sense and it mixes words from different registers (I'd never say "censi" and "pigliati" in the same sentence, the former is very formal/bureaucratical and the latter sounds colloquial).

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I think it is from an old text, like the other sentences the OP has asked in other questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Censo](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/C/censo.shtml):

> - Patrimonio, ricchezza sottoposti a tributo: famiglia di alto, di basso c.
> - estens. Tributo pagato allo Stato in proporzione ai propri averi
>
>   - Censo refers  to  the property (real estate and other income generating assets you own) on which taxes are levied by the State and also the taxes paid on those assets.

- With that respect, *censi passivi* refers to taxes/interest that must be paid on that specific asset.

*Censo* used with the meaning explained above is dated.